# Validation of textbox on selection of the radio button

Tags: oracle-apex

Currently I am having 2 radio button(Say A and B). On selection of the A , I am supposed to validate the textbox(say Name) and do not allow a null value on submit. However on selection of radio B, I can allow a null value on submit. How can I achieve this. Currently I am just enabling the switch button of the validation, but this does not allow me to submit the page if the radio button B is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

###### Page item P119_RADIO

- Type Radio Group
- List of Values Static, Values:

  - Display Value "Value A", Return Value "A"
  - Display Value "Value B", Return Value "B"

###### Page item P119_BUTTON

- Type Text Field

###### Submit Button

- action "Submit Page"

###### Validation

- Type Item is NOT NULL
- On page item P119_TEXT
- server-side condition of type "Item (P119_RADIO) = Value (A)".

[image]